# Using External Custom Web Component in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service, web-components

I wanted to know if it's possible to integrate an external **standard web component** in **LWC**. Like suppose I have **mycomponent.min.js** which exposes my-custom-component. And I want to use it  in html as `<my-custom-component></my-custom-component>`. Is there any way ? I tried importing min js file as **Static Resource** and loaded the script but it's not resolving my web component on  page. I am suspecting **Locker Service** might be blocking it. Anyone knows what can be done here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lightning Web Security Distortion Viewer says that [CustomElementRegistry.define](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/lws-distortion-viewer#CustomElementRegistry_define-value) is distorted. This means that Lightning Web Security should be able to support your use case. If you're still using Locker Service, you should consider enabling LWS, as Locker Service is not compatible with CustomElementRegistry (see the [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)).